# Nodemailer cannot send email from within Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemailer, alpine-linux

I've been searching/reading/trying everywhere on the Internet for about 3 weeks before posting here ...

**Context**:

- developing little website app
- technologies:

  - Next JS (ReactJs, HTML, CSS) for both frontend and backend (Node)
  - Linux as host (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
  - Docker's container to encapsulate app (based on node:alpine image) (Docker version 20.10.6)
  - Nodemailer Node's module to send email
- this is the code using Nodemailer to send the e-mail message:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.NM_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.NM_PORT),
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.NM_USER,
      pass: process.env.NM_PASS,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
  // console.log("User:");
  // console.log(process.env.NM_USER);

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: "Website <xxx@xxx.com>",
    to: "Website <xxx@xxx.com>",
    subject: "New contact",
    text: "NAME:\n" + req.body.data.name + "\n----------\nEMAIL:\n" + req.body.data.email + "\n----------\nBODY:\n" + req.body.data.body,
  }, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(info);
    }
  });
  console.log("Message sent: %s", info);

  res.json({
    a: req.body.data.name,
    b: req.body.data.email,
    c: req.body.data.body,
  });
};
```

**Issue**:

- when I try to send e-mail using Nodemailer launching my app from Linux host as "npm run start" or "npm run dev", mails get delivered
- ***when I try to send e-mail using Nodemailer launching my app from Docker's container, i get following error (from app's output itself)***

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

**What I already tried and what I observed:**

- `ping google.com` (and many others) works from within container (using `docker exec -ti container-name sh` command)
- starting container with `docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 ...` -> same result (error above)
- container's and host' `/etc/resolv.conf` are different (but I think that this might not be the point, as `ping` command correctly resolves, but feel free to say me wrong if I am)
- I am not a sys admin (i am a developer), so I don't know if iptables or ufw (firewall) may be implied in this thing (btw, it's difficult to install non pre-installed packages on node:alpine)
- Email server authentication is correct (both username, hostname, password) as it works correctly when i launch my app as `npm run start` or `npm run dev`
- switch container's network between bridge (default) bridge (custom with docker-compose) and host ... same issue (error above)

Anyone willing to help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out what wasn't working: I was using `docker-compose` WITHOUT `--env-file` option.

That way all the **environment variables** (e.g. PORT, HOST, PSWD, USR) I was trying to access within my app, were left `undefined` (this was because those environment variables weren't already built in during the building step - design choice, but rather accessed at runtime with `process.env`)

**SOLUTION (change `.env` file part as suits your situation):**

> `docker-compose --env-file ./.env.production`

Useful official resource (docker-compose)
[Docker-compose using --env-file option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option)